# Запуск через определенное количество секунд C#

Tags: c#

Как сделать так, если условие сработало, то через 30 секунд произвести `Server.Broadcast("Текст");` ?

```
if (crate_elite == true) {
    Server.Broadcast("Текст");
};
```

Comment: `TaskScheduler` вам в помощь с `TaskService`.

Comment: `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));`

Comment: если один поток то можно System.Threading.Thread.sleep(30000);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (crate_elite == true) {
Task.Factory.StartNew(async()=>
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    Server.Broadcast("Текст");
}
};
```